# TensorFlowのfeed_dict={x_data: x_val}の意味について

Tags: python, tensorflow

下のコードはtensor flowの、　リストに含まれている数字を計算グラフの演算に供給しその出力を書き出すコードなんですが
最後のfeed_dict={x_data: x_val}はどういう意味でしょうか？

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
#テンソルとプレースホルダを設定する。ここでは演算に供給するためのNumpy配列を作成する
import numpy as np

x_vals = np.array([1., 3., 5., 7., 9.])
x_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
m_const = tf.constant(3.)
#演算を定義する
my_product = tf.multiply(x_data, m_const)
#入力値をループで処理し、入力値ごとに除算の結果を出力する。
for x_val in x_vals:
    print(sess.run(my_product, feed_dict={x_data: x_val}))
```

Comment: Tensorflow の [API ドキュメント](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/)にある [`tf.Session.run`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run) の説明はご覧になりましたか？

Comment: すいません恥ずかしながら英語が苦手で調べながらでもわかりませんでした。お手数ですが教えてもらえるとありがたいです

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow Python API r1.3 によると、`tf.Session` クラスの [`run`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run) メソッドにはオプション引数として `feed_dict` を持っています。これは[辞書型](https://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)の引数で、その役割は下のように説明されています。

> The optional `feed_dict` argument allows the caller to override the value of tensors in the graph. Each key in `feed_dict` can be one of the following types:
>
> - If the key is a [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor), the value may be a Python scalar, string, list, or numpy ndarray that can be converted to the same dtype as that tensor. Additionally, if the key is a [`tf.placeholder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder), the shape of the value will be checked for compatibility with the placeholder.
> - If the key is a [`tf.SparseTensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor), the value should be a [`tf.SparseTensorValue`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensorValue).
> - If the key is a nested tuple of `Tensor`s or `SparseTensor`s, the value should be a nested tuple with the same structure that maps to their corresponding values as above.

これを和訳してみました。

> オプション引数 `feed_dict` を使うと、グラフ中のテンソルの値を上書きすることができます。`feed_dict` 中のキーと値の型は、以下のいずれかにすることができます。
>
> - キーが [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor) のとき、値は Python のスカラー、string、list、あるいは numpy ndarray であって、テンソルと同じ dtype に変換可能なものであれば良いです。更に、もしキーが [`tf.placeholder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder) であるなら、値の shape が placeholder と合うかどうかチェックされます。
> - キーが [`tf.SparseTensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor) のとき、値は [`tf.SparseTensorValue`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensorValue) であるべきです。
> - キーが `Tensor` や `SparseTensor` たちのネストしたタプルのとき、値はそれと同じ形をしたタプルで、それぞれのテンソルを上に書いてあるような値にうつすようなものであるべきです。

さて、今計算しようとしているのは以下の式でした。

```
x_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
m_const = tf.constant(3.)
my_product = tf.multiply(x_data, m_const)
```

これはつまり、`<float32型の何か> × 3.0` を計算しようとしているわけです。

今回のプログラムにおける `feed_dict` は、式の中に空いた穴（プレイスホルダー）であるところの `<float32型の何か>` を何にするかということを設定しています。

プログラム中の for ループは、プレイスホルダーに入れる値を変えながら上の式を計算しています。たとえば1回目のループでは `x_val` が `1.0` になるので、

```
run(my_product, feed_dict={x_data: 1.0})
```

が実行され、`1.0 × 3.0` が計算されることになります。

なお、これはマニュアルに書いてある1つ目の場合、つまり、キーが `tf.placeholder` というテンソル、値が Python スカラーの場合にあたります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。